# Can you see who downloaded your music files in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I have some music promos I am sending to friends and other musicians. Is there a way to see who has downloaded my files?

This will be good to know who has them and who was not interested.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. For basic users, no you cannot see who accessed data on your Google Drive account. But if you upgrade to a [Google Apps Unlimited](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6034782) or [Google Apps for Education](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2856827) account you will have access to the “Drive audit log.” As [explained here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579696?hl=en):

> The Drive audit log lists every time your domain's users view, create,
>   preview, print, update, delete, download, or share Drive content. This
>   includes content you create in Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, and other
>   Google Apps, as well as content created elsewhere that you upload to
>   Drive, such as PDFs and Word files.
>
> To access the Drive audit log, sign in to your Admin console and click
>   **Reports > Audit > Drive**. The page displays the following information:
>
> - **Event Description**—A summary of the event, such as "Larry created an item."
> - **User**—The user who performed the activity.
> - **Date**—The date the event occurred (displayed in your domain's default timezone).
> - **Event Name**—The action the user performed, such as View, Create, or Edit.
> - **IP Address**—The IP address from where the user performed the activity.
> - **File Type**—The type of Drive file the activity involves. Owner—The user who owns the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can .. but only with a third party plugin like [Orangedox for Drive](https://www.orangedox.com/drive).  Interstingly enough we have tons of muscians tracking their shared music using our services.

DISCLAIMER : I work for Orangedox :)

Answer (score 0):

For files shared outside your domain, Google Drive unlimited doesn't give you information about who watched or downloaded a file. Your only info in the auditing will be that "someone" viewed this file info, I think. You can only monitor that for people inside your domain.